# Javascript - If/Else If result

Tags: javascript, radio-group

I have these blocks:

```
function generateEmail(){
if 
(document.getElementById('emailOpt1').checked = "true") {
document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt1.value
}
else if
(document.getElementById('emailOpt2').checked = "true") {
document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt2.value
}
else if
(document.getElementById('emailOpt3').checked = "true") {
document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt3.value
}
else if
(document.getElementById('emailOpt4').checked = "true") {
document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt4.value
}
}
```

and this:

```
<div class="radioEmailType" id="emailClass">  
<input type="radio" id="emailOpt1" name=emailType value="email_c1">
 <label for="emailOpt1">class-one</label>
<input type="radio" id="emailOpt2" name=emailType value="email_c2">
 <label for="emailOpt2">class-two</label>
<input type="radio" id="emailOpt3" name=emailType value="email_c3">
 <label for="emailOpt3">class-three</label>
<input type="radio" id="emailOpt4" name=emailType value="email_c4">
 <label for="emailOpt4">class-four</label>
</div>
<button type="button" class="gButton" onclick=generateEmail()">GENERATE EMAIL</button>
<textarea id=generatedEmail></textarea></td></tr>
```

when I hit the 'generate email' button after selecting one of the 'radios', the code seems to revert the selection back to the first option as I keep on getting the first option on the `textarea`.

any ideas and a possibly a simpler way to do this will be appreciated.

**note:** I had to go this route since the user wants the radios to be buttons.

Comment: Compare with == and use keywords like true/false

Comment: When comparing things in a condition, use `==`. ex. `else if
(document.getElementById('emailOpt4').checked == true) {` A Boolean doesn't use quotes, strings use quotes. true, false they are Boolean.

Comment: ~was changing a lot in the code and that was one of the things i checked. when i use == on the conditional it doesn't seem to output the value on the textarea, it only does it when its a single '='

Comment: ~changing to == and boolean without quotes...

Comment: ~ugh! i fooled around for 30 mins, 5 mins to construct this question/post and 2 minutes to follow your instructions to get the problem fixed... thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

I fix it :

Change :

```
.checked = "true"
```

to :

```
.checked == true
```

Final code :

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div class="radioEmailType" id="emailClass">  
    <input type="radio" id="emailOpt1" name=emailType value="email_c1">
     <label for="emailOpt1">class-one</label>
    <input type="radio" id="emailOpt2" name=emailType value="email_c2">
     <label for="emailOpt2">class-two</label>
    <input type="radio" id="emailOpt3" name=emailType value="email_c3">
     <label for="emailOpt3">class-three</label>
    <input type="radio" id="emailOpt4" name=emailType value="email_c4">
     <label for="emailOpt4">class-four</label>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="gButton" onclick="generateEmail()">GENERATE EMAIL</button>
    <textarea id=generatedEmail></textarea>
    <script>
        function generateEmail(){
            if (document.getElementById('emailOpt1').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt1.value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('emailOpt2').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt2.value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('emailOpt3').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt3.value
            }
            else if (document.getElementById('emailOpt4').checked == true) {
            document.getElementById('generatedEmail').innerHTML = emailOpt4.value
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```